# Two quotation marks in sum task

Tags: chainlink

I have such a job:

```
type = "cron"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "gasOp"
forwardingAllowed = false
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
schedule = "CRON_TZ=UTC 0 */1 * * * *"
observationSource = """


opt_gas        [type=bridge name="gas" requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\": { \\"network\\": \\"opt\\"}}"]
opt_gas_maxFeePerGas        [type=jsonparse path="data,maxFeePerGas"]
opt_gas_maxPriorityFeePerGas        [type=jsonparse path="data,maxPriorityFeePerGas"]
opt_gas_baseFee        [type=jsonparse path="data,baseFee"]
opt_gas_estimatedFee [type="sum"]


opt_gas->opt_gas_maxFeePerGas
opt_gas->opt_gas_maxPriorityFeePerGas
opt_gas->opt_gas_baseFee
opt_gas_maxFeePerGas->opt_gas_estimatedFee
opt_gas_maxPriorityFeePerGas->opt_gas_estimatedFee
opt_gas_baseFee->opt_gas_estimatedFee




evershop_opt [type="http"
              method=POST
              url="http://localhost:3000/api/tax/classes/gas"
              requestData="{\\"300\\": {\\"id\\": 300,\\"price\\": $(opt_gas_estimatedFee)}}"
              allowUnrestrictedNetworkAccess=true
              ]



"""
```

In this task: **opt_gas_estimatedFee [type="sum"]** I gets a result that has two quotation marks as here:

```
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "98716e62-5c0b-49d2-8168-af059b9c657a",
      "createdAt": "2023-11-26T18:34:00.181724Z",
      "dotID": "opt_gas_estimatedFee",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2023-11-26T18:34:00.181766Z",
      "output": ""0.03394837"",
      "type": "sum"
```

in any other task gets the correct result in a single quotation mark, e.g:

```
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "863c888e-a6cd-438b-9fb8-9bc2bc122f73",
      "createdAt": "2023-11-26T18:34:00.181629Z",
      "dotID": "opt_gas_maxPriorityFeePerGas",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2023-11-26T18:34:00.181706Z",
      "output": "0.007436033",
      "type": "jsonparse"
```

How do I remove the double quotation mark?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your job configuration, it seems that your `sum` task is incorrect.

Can you please take a look at the following Chainlink [job task documentation](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/oracle-jobs/all-tasks#sum-task) for the `sum` task, and let me know if that fixes things?

Comment: No if I change this task to: my_sum_task [type="sum"
             values=<[ $(opt_gas_maxFeePerGas), $(opt_gas_maxPriorityFeePerGas), $(opt_gas_baseFee) ]>] receives the result as a string. I have changed the api settings to accept strings but would prefer to have a number here.

Comment: Can you post the result of the `opt_gas_maxFeePerGas`, `opt_gas_maxPriorityFeePerGas`, and `opt_gas_baseFee` tasks? Are they numbers represented as JSON strings, or numbers represented as JSON numbers?

Comment: "pol_gas_maxFeePerGas": 62.921777777, "pol_gas_maxPriorityFeePerGas": 29.193770191000006, "pol_gas_baseFee": 33.728007586,

Comment: Looking at your above taskRun with id `863c888e-a6cd-438b-9fb8-9bc2bc122f73`, I see an output for `opt_gas_maxPriorityFeePerGas` in string format (`"0.007436033"`), rather than number format (`0.007436033`) - I wonder if this is the issue here. If so, it's a rather unfortunate side effect of the `jsonparse` task.